# Inserting multiple foreign keys with aliases

Tags: sql, sqlite, with-statement

I'm trying to insert identities to foreign keys. Here's my code:

```
WITH p AS (SELECT id FROM tbl_place WHERE txt_place = "Place 1")
INSERT INTO tbl_sheet(txt_rep_no, txt_song_name, id_place, id_source_by, id_compiled_by, id_notation_by, id_type, blob_sheet1)
VALUES("1", "Song Name 1", p.id, 1, 1, 1, "", "")
```

This gives me error

> No such column p.id

How can I select and insert to multiple foreign keys?

Edit:
I tried adding "with" sentences but got error: "WITH": syntax error

```
INSERT INTO tbl_sheet(txt_rep_no, txt_song_name, id_place, id_source_by, id_compiled_by, id_notation_by, id_type, blob_sheet1)
WITH p AS (SELECT id FROM tbl_place WHERE txt_place = "Place 1")
WITH s AS (SELECT id FROM tbl_person WHERE txt_person = "Person 1")
WITH c AS (SELECT id FROM tbl_person WHERE txt_person = "Person 1")
WITH n AS (SELECT id FROM tbl_person WHERE txt_person = "Person 1")
SELECT "1", "Song 1", p.id, s.id, c.id, n.id, 1, ""
FROM p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because you're using it in the wrong order:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_sheet(txt_rep_no, txt_song_name, id_place, id_source_by, id_compiled_by, id_notation_by, id_type, blob_sheet1)
WITH p AS (SELECT id FROM tbl_place WHERE txt_place = "Place 1")
SELECT "1", "Song Name 1", p.id, 1, 1, 1, "", ""
FROM p
```

1. `INSERT INTO`
2. `WITH` clause
3. `SELECT` from table(-s) from the `WITH` clause

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I insert multiple aliases?

Comment: @onurcano, you're welcome! Give an example for better understanding what do you want to achieve

Comment: I mean id.place is ok. What about id_source_by, id_compiled_by, id_notation_by, and id_type? They are different tables. I tried adding "with" sentences but got error.

Comment: @onurcano, you can check this [SELECT](https://3v4l.org/RM0bit). For that purpose you have to prepare a complex `SELECT` statement with many subqueries (tables in `WITH` clause) and do the right `JOIN`s. Got it? Prepare `SELECT` which you wanna `INSERT`. Do it and you'll reach the point.

Comment: @onurcano, your update is weird. Keep in mind that `SELECT` has row(-s), where data is storred in one(many) line and these values will be inserted line-by-line. You need to prepare these lines of data. Your update doesn't follow that logic...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253058/discussion-between-aksen-p-and-onurcano).